# Display Correct Date Suffix

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fix [this widget](http://madanai1134.deviantart.com/art/Integrate-iWidgets-494832689) ([download](http://cl.ly/423s2C1l3Z3E/download/Integrate.zip)) as it's saying the date is the 01TH, 02TH and 03TH day of every month and I can't for the life of me work out why it isn't working. I have no experience with JS whatsoever, but I'm fairly competent with C# so the syntax isn't too hard to understand.

I realised this line is the culprit:

```
document.getElementById("monthFC").innerHTML = monthFC + " " + dateFC + "TH";
```

I tried replacing it with this code (I'm aware it's incorrect for the 11th, 12th and 13th), but it still fails:

```
if (dateFC % 10 == 1)
{
    document.getElementById("monthFC").innerHTML = monthFC + " " + dateFC + "ST";
}
else if (dateFC % 10 == 2)
{
    document.getElementById("monthFC").innerHTML = monthFC + " " + dateFC + "ND";
}
else if (dateFC % 10 == 3)
{
    document.getElementById("monthFC").innerHTML = monthFC + " " + dateFC + "RD";
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("monthFC").innerHTML = monthFC + " " + dateFC + "TH";
}
```

As far as I'm aware, the syntax is correct so I can only assume that I'm applying my modulus operator incorrectly (in C# I would guess it's storing the number as a string which is why it could fail, but I don't know if that's applicable here). If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

// There aren't many places left that you can use a switch statement, but this is one of them.

```
function nth(n){
    if(n%1) return n;
    var n1= n%100;
    if(n1>3 && n1<21) return n+'th';
    switch(n1%10){
        case 1: return n+'st';
        case 2: return n+'nd';
        case 3: return n+'rd';
        default: return n+'th';
    }
}
var A= [];
for(var i= 1; i<32; i++)A.push(nth(i));

A.join(', ');
```

//returned value:

```
1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 
14th, 15th, 16th, 17th, 18th, 19th, 20th, 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th, 
25th, 26th, 27th, 28th, 29th, 30th, 31st
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really neat code! I've got it sorted (commented to the guy below), but I'd like to incorporate your code instead so I'll get to work with that now.